# Using Wronskian to solve nonhomegeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I have the given ODE:

$$y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}\sin x$$

This has the homogeneous solution $y_h=C_1\cos(i-1)x+C_2\sin(-i-1)x$.

The particular solution, in the form $y_p=uy_1+vy_2$, we seek the Ansatz: $y_p=uy_1+vy_2=e^{-x}(\sin x+\cos x)$.  So $y_1=e^{-x}\sin x$ and $y_2=e^{-x}\cos x$

Then we aim to solve for $u$ and $v$   by  use of the variation of parameters formula:

$$u'y_1+v'y_2=0$$
$$u'y_1'+v'y_2'=f(x)$$

where $f(x)=e^{-x}\sin x$.

So here I should  use the Wronskian to facilitate the process. The Wronskian is naturally dependent on $y_1$ and $y_2$ and are $y_1=e^{-x}\sin x$ and $y_2=e^{-x}\cos x$.

So the Wronskian would be

\begin{equation}
\text{Det}\begin{vmatrix}
e^{-x}\sin x & e^{-x}\cos x\\
e^{-x}\cos x-e^{-x}\sin x & -e^{-x}\cos x-e^{-x}\sin x
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

My calculation gives:

$Det=-e^{-2x}\cos2x$

So how is this useful to solve the ODE, when I could just use the formula for variation of parameters?

Thanks

Comment: You are applying the method of variation of parameters. The Wronskian is just the denominator in the Cramer solution formula of the linear system. Your matrix is wrong, you have the same function in the first row, and some sign errors in the second line.

Comment: Thanks Lutz, corrected. So what is the point in solving for the Wronskian at all here?

Comment: There is still a sign error in the last entry, and the determinant should not have the second factor.

Comment: I corrected it. Still I  don't understand the point of the Wronskian here

Comment: It just appears when you eliminate in the linear system. Remove $y_2$ to get $W·u'=-y_2·f$. Remove $y_1$ to get $W·v'=y_1·f$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it seems the two resulting equations with u' and v' are impossible to solve, UNLESS we use the Wronskian in the form you wrote.

Comment: That is due to the still persisting sign error in $y_2'$.

Comment: Hint: $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$.

Comment: Got it. But I used your formula for the Wronskian, I see how it facilitates everything.

Comment: I think if you know one solution, you can use the Wronskian to find the other solution. Generally  for  $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t) y$ with solutions  $y_1$ and $y_2$,  the Wronskian is such that  $W(y_1 , y_2) (t) = c \cdot e^{\int p(t) dt}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''+2y'+2y=0$$
The solution of the homogeneous should be:
$$(r+1)^2-i^2=(r+1-i)(r+1+i)=0$$
$$y_h=e^{-x}(c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x)$$
Note that it's easier to first rewrite the DE as:
$$y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}\sin x$$
$$(ye^x)''+ye^x=\sin x$$
$$v''+v=\sin x$$
Then apply the method of variation of parameters.

Comment: How did you go from $C_1\cos(1-i)x+C_2\sin(-1-i)x$ to $e^{-x}(c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x)$?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz : You don't. In constructing that form of the basis solutions / solution basis you have mixed some ideas that do not go well together.

Comment: The solution of the DE should use exponential $e^{(-1 \pm i)x}$ then use Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos x +i \sin x$ @Luthier415Hz

Comment: Ah! Thanks, now I see.

Comment: PS: I got $$y_h=C_2e^{-x-ix}+C_2e^{-x+ix}$$, $$C_1e^{-x}(\cos x-i\sin x)+C_2e^{-x}(\cos x+i\sin x)$$, $$C_1e^{-x}\cos x-C_1e^{-x}i\sin x+ C_2e^{-x}\cos x+C_2e^{-x}i\sin x$$, $$y_h=(C_2-C_1)e^{-x}i\sin x+(C_1+C_2)e^{-x}\cos x$$

Comment: You can factorize $e^{-x}$  then $C_2-iC1=A$ is just a constant rename it  @Luthier415Hz

Comment: $$e^{-x}(A\sin x+B\cos x)$$ Thanks !!

Comment: You're welcome @Luthier415Hz

Answer (score 2):

It is generally easier to solve linear ODE with constant coefficients this way:

> - your homogeneous equation has root $r$ with multiplicity $m$ .
> - the full equation has a RHS of the form $P(x)e^{rx}$ with $P$ polynomial.
>
> Then you need to search for a particular solution in the form
> $Q(x)e^{rx}$ with $Q$ polynomial and $$\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m$$
>
> Although since the homogeneous solution will already have vanishing
> terms $(C_0+C_1x+\cdots+C_{m-1}x^{m-1})e^{rx}$, you can ignore them in
> the polynomial Q.

So here your homogeneous equation is $y''+2y'+2y=0$ of characteristic equation $$r^2+2r+2=0$$

It has roots $r=-1\pm i$ of multiplicity $m=1$.

The sinus can be rewritten as a combination of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$, therefore you RHS is $$\underbrace{\frac 1{2i}}_{P_1}e^{-x+ix}-\underbrace{\frac 1{2i}}_{P_2}e^{-x-ix}$$

Both terms of your RHS collide with the roots of the characteristic equation so since $P_1,\ P_2$ are constant polynomials, you need to search for particular solutions of the form $(ax+b)e^{-x+ix}$ and $(cx+d)e^{-x-ix}$

(i.e. $\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m=0+1=1$)

As said coefficients $b$ and $d$ can be ignored because we know already reporting in the ODE, the associated part will just vanish.

Therefore we can search for $ax\,e^{-x+ix}+cx\,e^{-x-ix}$ or directly in recomposed trig form $$\big(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)\big)xe^{-x}$$

Solving gives $A=-\frac 12$ and $B=0$.

Comment: It is 
Therefore we can search for $ax\,e^{-x+ix}+cx\,e^{-x-ix}$ or directly in recomposed trig form $$\big(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)\big)xe^{-x}$$ that is completely new to me. How?

Comment: See this related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485475/399263) for a justification on an example. This is theory, you can have a look at my homepage question "how to solve linear equations", it is for sequences, but exactly the same theory for linear ODE.